# Is there a way to force Google Podcast App to play podcasts in chronological order?

Tags: google, podcast

Looking for a way to autonomously play podcasts in the order they were recorded using Google Podcast Application.

But, irritatingly, Google Podcast always plays the latest (newest) episodes.  Even if it was already played (specifically, Google Podcast always plays the last few minutes of the latest previously listened to podcast).

This might be OK for news, but if you are trying to learn something, it may be all you can do from throwing your Android out the car window.

Comment: Anyways, I've been binging a several years old pod-cast ([Ologies](https://www.alieward.com/ologies)) driving to work and finally had enough frustrations trying to listen to episodes in order.  It's nuts!  Practically everything is hands free ... except for this order problem. (comment edited by a moderator)

Comment: OMGoodness, there are 100s of [Ologies](https://www.alieward.com/ologies) podcasts.  I was really hoping for a "do this one thing" solution. (I assume, for Ologies, I would have to do this 100s of times to play podcasts in order.) Thank you for your suggestion, but I'd like to hold out a bit more before asking you to turn this into an answer and accepting it.

Comment: This is interesting - I jumped back into Google Podcasts and selected an old podcast with an episode from 2022, and after it finished it moved automatically to the next released in chronological order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caveats*

- I don't use podcast apps or listen to podcasts but I was intrigued by the poor UX feature to investigate.
- Solutions proposed have undergone limited testing, yet posting it as an answer since it has an alternative app suggestion too.

---

[**Google Podcast app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.podcasts)

- Going by the Google community help [How to organise queue in Google podcasts since update (on Android)?](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/126953273?hl=en&msgid=147581145) of 2021, it appears that ordering podcasts was an existing feature but was removed after an app update. Two solutions have been proposed as working solutions:

1. [Manually arranging podcasts](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/126953273?hl=en&msgid=127655711)

> If you click the green checkmark on an episode in the queue, then select "Play Next", it will move the episode to the top of the queue.  It also remembers this new order.  Inexplicably, you can now sort that episode into any position, and it will remember.  Repeat this process for every episode in the queue, and you will be able to rearrange the episodes freely, and the app will retain the new order.  The worst part is that you have to do this every time you add an episode to the queue (you only have to do it for the added episode) if you want to change the position of the new episode.

One needs to use = on the left to order

2. [Using a PC to manually arrange podcasts](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/126953273?hl=en&msgid=147581145)
3. User jlehenbauer [commented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252553/is-there-a-way-to-force-google-podcast-app-to-play-podcasts-in-chronological-ord?noredirect=1#comment342384_252553)

> I jumped back into Google Podcasts and selected an old podcast with an episode from 2022, and after it finished it moved automatically to the next released in chronological order (*not tested by me*)

Since the OP listens to a channel (Ologies) having 100s of podcasts, these solutions [are not optimal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252553/is-there-a-way-to-force-google-podcast-app-to-play-podcasts-in-chronological-ord?noredirect=1#comment342247_252553)

---

Therefore, an alternative app solution is proposed below (I am not affiliated with it)

[**Podcast Guru**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reallybadapps.podcastguru)

1. Select "Ologies Channel"

[image]

2. On opening the podcast sub-topic list , by default it shows newest first

[image]

3. Click on the arrow buttons to reverse order to show oldest first

[image]

4. Additional features that would help OP

- Create a home screen shortcut to a podcast.
- "Hide completed" or "Mark all completed"
- Play chronologically, without the last few minutes of previous podcast being played

Comment: Thanks for putting this answer together.  I'm going to try the suggestions and if that doesn't work out the alternative Podcast Application.  Thanks.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the answer to improve it. A user's perspective matters much more